# Can't install application packages in AWS ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

I have created one aws instance, but while installing the packages like openssh-server and vim editor its throwing an error.

Errors were encountered while processing:

```
 python3-cryptography

 python3-urllib3

 python3-requests

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Setting up python3-cryptography (1.2.3-1ubuntu0.2) ...

/usr/bin/python3: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/python3: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

Comment: Please post your logs as text instead of image.

Comment: this may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed

Comment: Hi Joe I have gone through the link which you have provided, but still issue not resolved. Getting error code 1 and exit status is 127. 
When i check for python version it has 2.7. I tried to upgrade it to python 3 ver. its not happening. This error am getting *dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127